# Finding most appropriate Azure solution

Tags: azure

I am planning to build a solution for an automobile manufacturing company. The solution should allow vehicles to send on-board diagnostic (OBD) sensory and vehicle telemetry data to the cloud for analysis. We need to be able to identify individual vehicles from the data that is sent.
What would be the most appropriate Azure solution?
Choose the correct answer
  A.  Notification Hub
  B.  IoT Central
  C.  Event Hub
  D.  IoT Hub

Comment: Unfortunately this is a very broad question (and also a tool/service recommendation question). There's no objectively correct answer to this (though each technology you listed is different).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to send information to the devices, then Event Hub, otherwise IOT Hub.

Comment: PS: to query in real time you should use Stream Analytics.

Comment: I think you're answering a broad school assignment question. And also a tool/product/service recommendation question.

Comment: 100% agreed, but at the same time, it can help so, why not

Comment: Simply because there's no "objectively correct" answer. Even Stream Analytics is one of multiple options (again, falling into tool/service/product recommendations). It's really not possible to know what the right solution is, for such a generic high level requirement. And this is part of the site's guidelines.

Comment: Ok, looks like the OP is simply posting questions from some type of exam or study guide - here's yet another question just posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922185/authorization-in-azure (EDIT - Oops I see you've noticed this already and already commented)

Comment: I am posting questions here because I don’t know the answers of these questions. Stack overflow is a legitimate resource, why would I post some question from actual exam. I don't think these products/services were covered as part of my preparation, so I thought of asking experts. For an example I don't the difference between IoT HUB, Event Hub and IoT central.

Comment: @mikhil - the issue is that these questions are off-topic. For example: the question asked here is wide open for interpretation - there are many ways to build telemetry collection and observation, and there's no way to answer objectively with just a high level description and "choose one from this list." And each one of those services is fully documented within Azure's doc site. Your other question ("what best describes authorization") again isn't a programming question, and is something that is well-documented outside of Stack Overflow, asking the community to answer it for you.

Comment: @mikhil - what would happen, in your 2nd question, if 4 people posted 4 answers, each with a different response (PIN, driver license, birth certificate, password)? That wouldn't help you at all. And even if someone answered it correctly, they would need to provide a detailed explanation. Again, authorization and authentication is a very well documented subject.

Comment: Thank you so much, David. I posted my question after basic research in the documentation and I couldn't find what I was looking for is different real time examples of these services "Notification Hub, IoT Central, Event Hub and IoT Hub

Comment: As you also mentioned that different members/experts from this forum provided different answers for the question I posted, that means an entry level person definitely needs help. Anyways I have got your message. I will look for other options. Thanks again